# How to fix notifyDataSetChanges is not working

Tags: android, android-studio

This is an `Image Search App` Using `Pixabay API` The first search is working but the second one does not refresh the recyclerview, my query URI is changing but it does not change the views. Where should i put `notifyDataSetChanged`?

`MainActivity`:

```
public void makeImageSearchQuery(){
    String imageQuery = mSearchBoxEditText.getText().toString();
    URL imageSearchUrl = NetworkUtils.buildUrl(imageQuery);
    mUrlDisplayTextView.setText(imageSearchUrl.toString());


    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, imageSearchUrl.toString(), null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    mImageList = NetworkUtils.parseJSON(mImageList, response);
                    mImageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(MainActivity.this, mImageList);
                    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mImageAdapter);

                }

            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();

        }
    });

    mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    mRequestQueue.add(request);

    hideKeyboard();

}
```

`ImageAdapter`:

```
public ImageAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Image> imageList){
    mContext = context;
    mImageList = imageList;

}

@Override
public ImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    return new ImageViewHolder(v);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ImageViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Image currentImage = mImageList.get(position);

    String imageUrl = currentImage.getImageUrl();
    String creatorName = currentImage.getCreator();
    int likeCount = currentImage.getLikes();

    holder.mTextViewCreator.setText(creatorName);
    holder.mTextViewLikes.setText("Likes: " + likeCount);

    Picasso.with(mContext)
            .load(imageUrl)
            .fit()
            .centerInside()
            .into(holder.mImageView);
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mImageList.size();
}

public class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    private ImageView mImageView;
    private TextView mTextViewCreator;
    private TextView mTextViewLikes;

    public ImageViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        mTextViewCreator = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_creator);
        mTextViewLikes = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_likes);
    }

}
     }
```

`parseJSON`:

```
public static ArrayList<Image> parseJSON(ArrayList<Image> mImageList, JSONObject response){

    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("hits");

        for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
            JSONObject hit = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            String creatorName = hit.getString("user");
            String imageUrl = hit.getString("webformatURL");

            int likeCount = hit.getInt("likes");

            mImageList.add(new Image(imageUrl, creatorName, likeCount));

           


        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return mImageList;


}
```

Comment: I couldn't find where you called `notifyDataSetChanged()`  also show what you have tried

Comment: I put my `mImageAdaper.notifyDataSetChanged()` after `mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mImageAdapter);` in the `onResponse` clause. I've also tried to place it in `parseJSON` method everytime I add `Image` object inside `mImageList` Array.